# omxplayer repository package for bullseye

Tags: pi-4, omxplayer, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I'm trying to get a hardware accelerated playback of H264 videos, e.g. the [Big Buck Bunny sample](https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_10MB.mp4).

I have

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ bullseye main
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free
```

in my `sources.list`, and I see there are some `omxplayer` packages in `http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/o/omxplayer/`. Yet `apt-get install omxplayer` cannot find an installation candidate.

How can I properly install `omxplayer` on bullseye?

PS.

Installing `omxplayer_20190723+gitf543a0d-1+bullseye_armhf.deb` seems to work, but I would prefer my packages to be managed by `apt` rather than manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that omxplayer has been depreciated, meaning that there are not any plans at this time to make it work on Bullseye. I don't know what options there are that you could use to replace it off-hand.

Answer (score 1):

For me, `omxplayer` got installed automatically after doing `apt --fix-broken install` - I don't really understand how `apt` finds it, but there you go. However, the installation doesn't work out of the box. The instruction listed here:
https://github.com/dasl-/piwall2/issues/18
sorted the issue out for me (on a Raspberry Pi model 1).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).